# Dealing with NoReverseMatch error in Django

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I'm working with Django right now.

I have the line of code `path('articles/<int:pk>', views.Article_List_View.as_view(), name='article-detail')`.

Whenever I run the server, I'm thrown the error

```
NoReverseMatch at /catalog/articles/ 
Reverse for article-detail' with arguments '('828073a5-f232-46f2-aa35-25206b95a18f',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\Z'].
```

I understand that the article with that ID is not in that folder, but I can't figure out how to get it to save to that folder.

Comment: '828073a5-f232-46f2-aa35-25206b95a18f' is not match int, it is a string. So it doesn't match "<int:pk>"